# Transform mixed-case word into (multiple) Capitalized words?

Tags: javascript

How do I "normalise" caps & spaces?

Example: `coreControllerC4a` automatically turns into `Core Controller C4a` when function is called?

Comment: for what is this "normalization" for?

Comment: 1) Define rules 2) Implement 3) ??? 4) Profit. (Seriously, there is no *standard* method -- or even name? -- for this, but it's doable relatively easily for *most* cases with a regex split followed by a map operation.)

Comment: You will have to define the rules for what should be captilized, not capitalized and what the algorithm is for determining where spaces go before anyone can help.  If you cannot do that, this question is not answerable and will need to be closed.

Comment: Any caps = add a space and cap first letter of each word. That's about it. Like cccCccccCcc would be Ccc Ccccc Ccc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting example

```
"coreControllerC4a".split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
```

which results in

```
["core", "Controller", "C4a"]
```

Of course, there are many counter-examples, and this doesn't cover Unicode, but it does show using a regular expression to split a string. (Note the use of a look-ahead to avoid consuming any data at the split.) Now it's just a matter of transforming ("map"ing) each element to the correct case.

Happy coding.

Comment: thanks, helps so much .. coudlnt figure out what method to do this with